# I can not distinguish between taskbar windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar

I have a problem with my taskbar.

I am running 5 x chrome windows where each have around 10-30 tabs.

My problem is that the information in the taskbar window change when a new tab is chosen. Therefor I can not find the correct window every time, and often have to run through all 5. This is in the long run pretty time consuming, anyone know a way to "fix" this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question so this suggestion may not be helpful, but right click on the task bar, properties, and beside Taskbar buttons choose "never combine" . Does that help?

Comment: no, I never combine already. If not it would be a completely disaster. But I would like each windows to be named 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 or something like that.. Instead of a random link-name.. Annoying

Comment: ahhh thanks for finding that ! how do I upvote you in coment

Comment: This is not limited to Windows 10, the same behavior occurs in Windows 7 as well.

Comment: I never said so @Dan

Comment: @user622780 you say so with the [tag:windows-10] tag: "For questions specific to Windows 10."

Comment: I definitely don't, since I am generalizing the problem with the just "windows" tag. I just inform that I am using windows 10, with that tag, @Dan Henderson

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plug in in Chrome to rename the tabs which *may* help

[Rename tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/renametab/mkailnbloeepkajmoblllhhhckpbbncg)

> This extension lets you change the title of the current tab to something more descriptive. You can even 'lock' a title to a tab, even if you navigate to a different page! Please note that this will not work well on websites which dynamically change the tile of the page, or only change parts of the page while navigating (e.g Facebook), or if you type a new URL in (but I'm trying to find a way around the last one)

Comment: unfortunately its a retarded plugin, I just tried it.. I wont change taskbar title, only tabs I just learned. It can chance the title in taskbar, but only if you are on the same tab, which makes it completely lame:)